# How to find a button id under anchor tag?

Tags: jquery, button, asp.net-mvc-4, anchor

I am working on MVC4 jQuery. I need to find a button id which is under an `anchor` tag.
Here is my jQuery code:

```
// drop event handler
addEvent(dropAreas, 'drop', function (event) {
    alert(5);
    if (event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();

    // get dropped object
    var iObj = event.dataTransfer.getData('obj_id');
    var oldObj = document.getElementById(iObj);

    // get inner text
    var linkText = oldObj.innerHTML;
    oldObj.className += 'hidden';

    // remove object from DOM
    oldObj.parentNode.removeChild(oldObj);

    // add similar object in another place
    this.innerHTML += '<a id="' + iObj + '" draggable="true">' + linkText + '<button id="btnAdd " style="height:20px;width:20px;">Add</button></a>';

    // and update event handlers
    updateHandlerDrag();

    this.style.borderColor = "#ccc";
    return false;
});
```

In this line I define a button in the above code:

```
 this.innerHTML += '<a id="' + iObj + '" draggable="true">' + linkText + '<button id="btnAdd " style="height:20px;width:20px;">Add</button></a>';
```

In above code I had given one button in an anchor tag, I need to fire that id in the code below:

```
// add SubMenu
var addColBtn = document.querySelectorAll('#btnAdd ');
addEvent(addColBtn, 'click', function (event) {
    alert('addingSubmenu');

    if (event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();
    alert('adding');
    // recalculate widths for columns
    var oCols = document.querySelector('div.columns');
    alert(sub);
    var iChilds = oCols.childElementCount + 1;
    var dWidth = 50 / iChilds;

    // add single column
    oCols.innerHTML += '<div class="columns" id="drop_' + (iChilds + 1) + '" droppable="true"><img src="images/delete.png" onclick="removeColumn(this)" /></div>';

    // set new widths
    for (var i = 0; i < iChilds; i++) {
        oCols.children[i].style.width = dWidth + '%';
    }

    // update handlers
    updateHandlerDrop();

    return false;
});
```

How can I do this?

Comment: what are you trying to do with this line of code `this.innerHTML += '<a id="' + iObj + '" draggable="true">' + linkText + '<button id="btnAdd " style="height:20px;width:20px;">Add</button></a>';` ?? Inserting a button inside an anchor tag is completely WRONG !

Comment: yes i want to insert button couls u help me to do it

Comment: "i want to insert button" can you elaborate a lil more pls ?

Comment: yes yaseer  now i am working on widges k i have a link button if i drop in one place it will be drop now i need to drop one more link under link one for example plz chek this i have to do this plz check out  http://www.script-tutorials.com/bottom-menu-builder-html5/

Comment: here we are droping lind one in columns now i need to drop one more under before one check the live demo    http://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/270/index.html

Comment: have you seen the answers posted below.

Comment: did you see the sourcecode of the links you have posted here ?? Nowhere do they say use button inside links

Comment: mens my task to do here we are droping links in one place right now if we place one more it will take like anothe drop now here i want to drop lind like this is first drop for link one so i had to create button clck function like adding place for drop links under links

Comment: @yasser i had written the button once we drop the link it shod bind with button and with click button i need to add some place for dorp another link under the link like (Add Column in above sight)

Comment: its not working @Milind Anantwar

Comment: @shakil: ok.first of all you are not suppose to put button inside anchor tag.otherwise you are appending the inner html correctly.why dont you add button after anchor tag.something like this

`this.innerHTML += '<a id="' + iObj + '" draggable="true">' + linkText + '</a><button id="btnAdd " style="height:20px;width:20px;">Add</button>';`

Comment: @Milind Anantwar yes i had checked out  yes right its working but i need write a click function for btnAdd "id" it is not working as of written above code

Comment: and thanks for reply i need some more help

Comment: why do you want anchor then?
just append button tag with `id="btnAdd"` to innerhtml.

Comment: just check it once " script-tutorials.com/demos/270/index.html "  here one link droping in one place right once it is droped i need to generate button for droped lind and need to fire that button under it

Comment: check this one also u wil get complete idea about it                      http://www.script-tutorials.com/bottom-menu-builder-html5/

Comment: so basically you want button to be enabled for dropped link.for that you have 2 options:
1)replace your anchor tag by button of same height and width.
2)enable on click to anchor without adding button.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18463/discussion-between-shakil-and-milind-anantwar)

Answer (score 0):

```
     $('a').click(function(){
       console.log( $(this).find('button').attr('id'))
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly**, what are you trying to do with this line of code ???

```
this.innerHTML += '<a id="' + iObj + '" draggable="true">' + linkText + '<button id="btnAdd " style="height:20px;width:20px;">Add</button></a>';
```

If I fill in some values to the html string above a markup([fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/yrshaikh/H9Fby/)) like the following will be prepared....

```
<a id="someId" draggable="true">SomeText<button id="btnAdd " style="height:20px;width:20px;">Add</button></a>​
```

Whatever you are trying here... you are doing it the ***wrong*** way. Inserting a button inside an anchor tag is completely WRONG !

**Secondly**, to get button/anchor tag using jquery, you can use jquery selectors, such as

```
var selectedItem = $("#uniqueIdGoesHere");
```

and to trigger the click event you can write this

```
$("#uniqueIdGoesHere").bind("click", function(){
  // write here what needs to be triggered.
});
```